# How to use node fetch and express at the same time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node-fetch

I want to get data from API and show it. I use node-fetch and express. Node-fetch is not supported 'require'. Therefore, I use `import fetch from 'node-fetch'`. For this, I added  `"type": "module"` in package.json. I get an error when I try to add express. I tried `const app = require('express')();` I get **ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead
This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and 'C:\Users\name\Desktop\homework\package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.
at file:///C:/Users/tahan/Desktop/bcfm_case/case.js:4:13** error.

I tried `import * as app from 'express'` . I get **app.get is not a function**.

How to use node-fetch and express at the same time?

Comment: If you want to use the CommonJS version of `node-fetch` you need to install the older version `npm install node-fetch@2` or load it via the async `import()` function. See [documentation](https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch#commonjs) for more info

Comment: If you wanted to import `express` using ESM, you'd need to do `import express from 'express'; const app = express()` - you confused `import * as X` with `import X` and you also dropped the function call you had at the end of `require('express')()` before...